# How to update record with OneToMany relationship in Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have a user entity and I'm trying to update it from a UserService. The problem comes when I try to update a property which is set as an array collection.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param \Doctring\Common\Collections\Collection $property
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Countries",mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $countries;
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to somehow delete all the $countries before I set them back or if there's a way to select which ones to delete and set up the different ones....this is what my updateUser method looks so far:

```
public function updateUser($user) {
    $entity = $this->getUser($user['id']);
    if (!$entity)
        throw new Exception('Error saving user!');
    $countries = $this->getCountriesArray($user); //countries already set in the db
    $tempCountries = array();
    $delete = array();
    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        $found = false;
        if (in_array($country, $user['countries'])) {
            $tempCountries[] = $country;
        } else {
            $delete[] = $country;
        }
    }
    $tempCountries = array_unique(array_merge(                //combine the countries from the db we want to leave 
                                        $tempCountries,       //with those the user selected
                                        $user['countries']));
    ...
    //here I need something to remove the countries in $delete...right?
    ...
    $entity->setEmail($user['email']);
    $entity->setResponsable($user['responsable']);
    $entity->setPassword($this->createPass($user['password']));
    $entity->setUrl($user['url']);
    $entity->setRole($user['role']);

    $modelCountries = array();
    foreach($tempCountries as $c) {
        $p = new Countries();
        $p->setCountryName($c);
        $p->setUser($entity);
        $modelCountries[] = $p;
    }
    $entity->setCountries($modelCountries);

    $this->em->persist($entity);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

please stackOverflow... give me a hand making sense out of this.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on your use case.

As you said, you can either delete all countries before to set the new ones, or compute the delta, and update only the needed ones.

- What countries are you providing to your service? The delta? Or full list?
- Do you have performance constraints? If yes, what is the cost of a DELETE statements vs SELECT then UPDATE?

Compute delta, then UPDATE can be tricky and difficult, in most case, you better want to just DELETE all and INSERT.

Comment: well, I don't wanna bust my brains too much at this point, it's just a test app...to try to figure how doctrine 2 works... I could just get all countries related to the entity by doing `$entity->getCountries();` but how would I delete them?

Answer (score 0):

For my current and personal choice I am using DQL to DELETE all owing side rows for the mapped entity and then inserting the new one.

```
class Rule
{

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Tier", mappedBy="rule", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="ruleId", referencedColumnName="ruleId")
 * @var Tier[]
 */
public $tiers;
```

So when I am passing new Tier in my call I am simply Deleting the all Tiers for that Role from the Rule Mapper

```
public function resetTiers($ruleId)
{
    $modelClass = "Tier";

    $q = $this->doctrineEntityManager->createQuery("Delete from $modelClass m where m.rule =" . $ruleId);
    $numDeleted = $q->execute();

    return $numDeleted;
}
```

and then calling the usual

`$this->doctrineEntityManager->persist($rule);
     $this->doctrineEntityManager->flush();`

Hope that helps